# How to target CSS :after element with the tilde selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The `::after` selector will inserts something after the content, is this targetable with the preceding selector `~`?

For example, HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    ::after       
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul::after { 
    content: ''; 
    display: block; 
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

ul li:hover ~ ::after {
    background: blue;
}
```

**CODE EXAMPLE**

Below you are able to find a working version of what I am after. However I did this with the "sub-menu-bar" div included. Now it seems the `::after` pseudo element is positioned at the exact location in the DOM inspector. It would be nice if it could be done without the div.

The reason why the submenu bar is on the UL is because I don't want the bar to move when switching between two items which have a submenu.

```css
ul, li
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

a 
{
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a > * 
{
user-select: none;
}

ul.menu
{
position: relative;

display: flex;
width: 100%;

flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;

background: #FFF;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item > a
{
padding: 0px 10px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 0.3s;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item > ul.sub-menu
{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;

display: flex;
width: 100%;
height: 0px;

align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
transition: height 0.4s;

color: #FFF;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item
{
overflow: hidden;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item > a 
{
padding: 0px 10px; 

transform: translateY(100%);
opacity: 1;

transition-property: transform, opacity;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52, 0.16, 0.24, 1);
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

ul.menu > div.sub-menu-bar
{
content: '';

display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 2px;

flex-basis: 100%;
transition: height 0.4s;

background: #000;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu
{
height: 50px;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children:hover > ul.sub-menu > li.menu-item > a 
{
transform: translateY(0%);
opacity: 1;
transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children:hover ~ div.sub-menu-bar 
{
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a>Item #1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a>Item #2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Subitem #2.1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Subitem #2.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children">
    <a>Item #3</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Subitem #3.1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a>Subitem #3.2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item"><a>Item #4</a></li>
<li class="menu-item"><a>Item #5</a></li>
<div class="sub-menu-bar"></div> <!-- Can we avoid this with ::after pseudo element? -->
</ul>

<p>Content below the navigation.</p>
```

Comment: share your full code and what you are trying to achieve and I am sure there is a solution without trying what is impossible to do

Comment: With pure css it is not possible to change the background color of an element `ul::after` that is located after the parent `ul` of the `li:hover` (child of ul).

Comment: There is an approach with pure css, @bron - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This does not require a `~`. the `~` selector selects all siblings after the element. The pseudo element `::after` is inside the `li`.

`li:hover ~ li` would for example target all `li` elements after the `li` that is hovered.

For what you want to do, use:

```
ul li:hover:after {
    background: blue;
}
```

**Edit**:

Sorry, I didn't see the after applied to ul. This is not possible with pure CSS as there is no "parent" selector. You can only use `ul:hover:after` (or anything higher in hierarchy than ul) to target the `after` element.
What you could do:

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

```css
li:hover ~ li:last-of-type {
 //something
}
```

Comment: The problem is the pseudo element `::after` is not on the li element but on the ul element. That is the one I need to target, which looks impossible. I tried your code for the sake of it, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the after applied to ul. Yes, you're right. This is not possible with pure CSS as there is no "parent" selector. You can only use ul:hover:after or anything higher in hierarchy than ul.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought. The weird part is when I add a `div` at the place where you can see the `::after` in the example above I am able to target it by using `ul li:hover ~ div`, that's why I thought `ul li:hover ~ ::after` would be legit.

Comment: Yes, this can look a little confusing when looking at the inspector. The after element lives on the UL though. As you noticed you can use any other element to achieve what you want, but make sure if you're inside ul use li to keep the html valid. Othwise use a div a wrapper.

Comment: It's unfortunate. I can't seem to find a reason why you wouldn't be able to target the ::after pseudo element the same way. Anyways thanks for your time. I update the question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

> When I hover on a specific list item (`li`) targeted with a class name.
>   I like the background color of the `::after` element to change, which is
>   located on `ul::after`.

Yes, you can achieve this effect using `pointer-events`.

The way to do it is to apply to both the `<ul>` and the `<li>` the style:

```
ul, li {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and apply to the hoverable `<li>` the style:

```
li.hover-over-this {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```css
ul {
position: relative;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: white;
cursor: pointer;
}

li {
width: 50%;
padding: 6px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: 24px;
background-color: red;
list-style: none;
}

ul:hover::after {
content: 'Hovering!';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
line-height: 100px;
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

ul, li {
pointer-events: none;
}

li.hover-over-this {
pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="hover-over-this">Hover Over This</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

---

Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Haha I upvoted for the creativity! Unfortunately what I failed to mention is that the ul is the navigation and the li are navigation items. So `pointer-events: none` would result in a useless navigation. I will rework my question.

Comment: Drat. I thought I'd come up with a properly innovative solution. :-)

Comment: In that you succeeded haha respect to you man. You taught me how to include code snippets so at least I got value out of it ;-) I posted the code in my question.